# Running a python docker with miniconda3 and geopandas

Tags: python, docker

I create a docker to run a python script with data inputs as arguments.
Sounds straighforward, I proceed by

**(1) Create the library image**

Dockerfile_libraries:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN conda config --add channels conda-forge && conda update -y conda \
&& conda install -y geopandas

docker build -t img1 -f Dockerfile_libraries .
```

**(2) Add the code and the data**

Dockerfile_analysis:

```
FROM img1 
RUN mkdir -p /home/
COPY /data/ /home/data/
COPY myScript.py /home/
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/home/myScript.py", "/home/data/data1", "/home/data/data2"]
```

docker build -t img2 -f Dockerfile_analysis .

**(3) Run it:**

```
docker run img2
```

But then it says

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /opt/conda/share/proj failed
```

and I stop it with a ctrl-c

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I think this issue is related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364421/how-to-make-proj-work-via-anaconda-in-google-colab). According to that post, the problem is related to the use of pyproj in the base environment. Unfortunately, the proposed solution does not generalize well.